# How do I get a 'list' (or something similar) of functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, functions

I'm solving an NDSolve equation, like:

```
enito = 10;
sm = Range[enito];


For [a = 1, a < (enito + 1), a++, 

sm[[a]] = 
  NDSolve[{y''[x] + a*y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 30}]]
```

And then I do:

```
valor = Range[enito];

For[a = 1, a < (enito + 1), a++, 

 valor[[a]] = 
With[{exp = Through[({y} /. First[sm[[a]]])[#]]}, exp &]];
```

Up to this point, I think everything is alright. Now, I'm interested in construct a list of functions with valor[[a]]. For example if I define:

```
F[x_] := x^2
```

I'm interested in have something like:

```
gr[[a]][x_] := valor[[a]]/F[x]
```

But I can't get anything similar. What can I use for obtain an list with the 10 elements of gr[[a]], making them a function (using F[x] for each one of them)? *i.e*, for have a list (each element, a different a) of functions of *x*?

I'd appreciate a lot all the answers. Thank you.

Comment: Minimalistic problems are nice. Make it clear, what is your goal. At the moment ti seems only the last line is relevant.

Comment: Okay, I'll try:

I'm just searching for a way of get a list of functions. I'm interested in evaluate each *a* solution for the NDsolve, divided by x^2, and evaluated at a given x*.

Comment: This does give you a list of functions, without me understanding any of your NDSolve stuff. `fList = Table[a/#^2 & /. a -> aa, {aa, Range[1.22, 1.88, 0.11]}]`

Comment: And if my function F[x_] is numerical, and I cannot get an analytical expression for it?

Comment: If you would replace the last line with `gr[a_,x_] := valor[[a]]/F[x]`, you would not be happy?

Comment: That can be a great solution, I didn't thought of that! It was a lot simpler than I guessed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
gr=Table[With[{x=#},valor[[i]]/F[x]]&,{i,Length@valor}]
```

Can this help?

Comment: That was another way of solving my problem, thanks.

Comment: But unlike mine this actually does, what is asked in the title of the question. You perhaps should accept this answer.